# Can I copy an iPhone to a second iPhone of mine with different SIM cards and use both?

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

I want two iPhones with different phone numbers but the same Apple ID.

Is there any problem copying the first via iCloud and Mac to the second and using both?

Comment: No problem, however iPhones do support multiple sim cards, with the second being an esim. You should be able to get an esim from your carrier so that you can have both phone numbers on a single phone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, surely you can do that.

In general, there's nothing hindering you from having multiple phones logged into the same Apple-ID - but with different SIM-cards and phone numbers. I.e. you do not need to copy an existing phone in order to achieve this - you can also just setup a new phone as a "blank" device and login to your Apple-ID.